# ¿Como ocultar columnas de un datatable en caso que muestre para celulares con boostrap?

Tags: jquery, html5, bootstrap, datatables

Por ejemplo tengo un datatable de 5 columnas, que se ven todas con la definición de col-lg, pero cuando quiero probar o verla en celular(col-xs), me gustaría se que pudiera ocultar las ultimas tres columnas.

¿Como se podría lograr hacer eso?¿Alguien podría mostrar algún ejemplo?

Por ejemplo tengo el siguiente codigo:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var table = $('#example').DataTable( {
    "scrollY": "200px"
  } );


} );

<table id="example" class="display" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Position</th>
        <th>Office</th>
        <th class="hidden-xs">Age</th>
        <th class="hidden-xs">Start date</th>
        <th class="hidden-xs">Salary</th>
    </tr>
</thead>

<tfoot>
    <tr>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Position</th>
        <th>Office</th>
        <th>Age</th>
        <th>Start date</th>
        <th>Salary</th>
    </tr>
</tfoot>

<tbody> 
    <tr>
        <td>Vivian Harrell</td>
        <td>Financial Controller</td>
        <td>San Francisco</td>
        <td>62</td>
        <td>2009/02/14</td>
        <td>$452,500</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Timothy Mooney</td>
        <td>Office Manager</td>
        <td>London</td>
        <td>37</td>
        <td>2008/12/11</td>
        <td>$136,200</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Jackson Bradshaw</td>
        <td>Director</td>
        <td>New York</td>
        <td>65</td>
        <td>2008/09/26</td>
        <td>$645,750</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Olivia Liang</td>
        <td>Support Engineer</td>
        <td>Singapore</td>
        <td>64</td>
        <td>2011/02/03</td>
        <td>$234,500</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Bruno Nash</td>
        <td>Software Engineer</td>
        <td>London</td>
        <td>38</td>
        <td>2011/05/03</td>
        <td>$163,500</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Sakura Yamamoto</td>
        <td>Support Engineer</td>
        <td>Tokyo</td>
        <td>37</td>
        <td>2009/08/19</td>
        <td>$139,575</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Thor Walton</td>
        <td>Developer</td>
        <td>New York</td>
        <td>61</td>
        <td>2013/08/11</td>
        <td>$98,540</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Finn Camacho</td>
        <td>Support Engineer</td>
        <td>San Francisco</td>
        <td>47</td>
        <td>2009/07/07</td>
        <td>$87,500</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Serge Baldwin</td>
        <td>Data Coordinator</td>
        <td>Singapore</td>
        <td>64</td>
        <td>2012/04/09</td>
        <td>$138,575</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Zenaida Frank</td>
        <td>Software Engineer</td>
        <td>New York</td>
        <td>63</td>
        <td>2010/01/04</td>
        <td>$125,250</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Zorita Serrano</td>
        <td>Software Engineer</td>
        <td>San Francisco</td>
        <td>56</td>
        <td>2012/06/01</td>
        <td>$115,000</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Jennifer Acosta</td>
        <td>Junior Javascript Developer</td>
        <td>Edinburgh</td>
        <td>43</td>
        <td>2013/02/01</td>
        <td>$75,650</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Cara Stevens</td>
        <td>Sales Assistant</td>
        <td>New York</td>
        <td>46</td>
        <td>2011/12/06</td>
        <td>$145,600</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Hermione Butler</td>
        <td>Regional Director</td>
        <td>London</td>
        <td>47</td>
        <td>2011/03/21</td>
        <td>$356,250</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Lael Greer</td>
        <td>Systems Administrator</td>
        <td>London</td>
        <td>21</td>
        <td>2009/02/27</td>
        <td>$103,500</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Jonas Alexander</td>
        <td>Developer</td>
        <td>San Francisco</td>
        <td>30</td>
        <td>2010/07/14</td>
        <td>$86,500</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Shad Decker</td>
        <td>Regional Director</td>
        <td>Edinburgh</td>
        <td>51</td>
        <td>2008/11/13</td>
        <td>$183,000</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Michael Bruce</td>
        <td>Javascript Developer</td>
        <td>Singapore</td>
        <td>29</td>
        <td>2011/06/27</td>
        <td>$183,000</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Donna Snider</td>
        <td>Customer Support</td>
        <td>New York</td>
        <td>27</td>
        <td>2011/01/25</td>
        <td>$112,000</td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Quiero que en pantalla de pc escritorio me muestre todas las columnas de la tabla, pero cuando se achique, o mejor dicho que cuando se muestra para celular(col-xs), oculte las ultimas 3 columnas.

El asunto es que utilizo el class="hidden-xs, en este caso los th dentro del thead de la tabla, pero solo me oculta los encabezado, la idea es que se aplique a toda la columna, sin estar agregando hidden-xs en cada td del tbody que quiera ocultar.

Comment: como quieres ocultarlas? Predefinidamente? Con un boton en la web?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Para ocultar las ultimas 3 columnas de 5, debes colocarlo de esta manera:

```
$( "#btnOcultar" ).on( "click", function() {
            $('#tabla').DataTable().destroy();
            $('#tabla').DataTable( {
                "pagingType": "full_numbers",
                "columnDefs": [
                    {
                        "targets": [ 2 ],
                        "visible": false,
                        "searchable": false
                    },
                    {
                        "targets": [ 3 ],
                        "visible": false,
                        "searchable": false
                    },
                    {
                        "targets": [ 4 ],
                        "visible": false,
                        "searchable": false
                    }
                ]
            } );
        } );
```

Primero, destruyes el Datatable asignado al principio, si es que lo agregaste al table al momento de cargar la página, luego le asignas nuevamente el Datatable con las columnas que quieras ocultar. 
Puedes manejarlo con botones, o con eventos que suceden en tu página, yo tengo dos botones, uno para ocultar y otro para mostrar. Para mostrarlo nuevamente, lo único que debes hacer es cambiar **false** por **true**, tanto en el atributo **visible**, como en **searchable**.

Answer (score 3):

Puedes echar un vistazo a las Responsives utilities de bootstrap.

[Bootstrap responsive utilities](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#responsive-utilities)

Igual me gustaria saber un poco de tu código para ver si te podemos ayudar más.

**EDITO**

teniendo todos los datos podemos hacer una función que nos ayude a hacer lo que pides. usando tu tabla como ejemplo.Usa funcion de jQuery, find y usa el filtro eq y el numero de las columnas que quieres ocultar.

```
  $(document).ready(function() {
  var table = $('#example').DataTable( {
    "scrollY": "200px"
  } );
     $("#table tr").find('td:eq(3)').each(function () {
       $(this).addClass("hidden-xs");
     });
     $("#table tr").find('td:eq(4)').each(function () {
       $(this).addClass("hidden-xs");
     });
     $("#table tr").find('td:eq(5)').each(function () {
       $(this).addClass("hidden-xs");
     });
} );

<table id="example" class="display" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Position</th>
        <th>Office</th>
        <th class="hidden-xs">Age</th>
        <th class="hidden-xs">Start date</th>
        <th class="hidden-xs">Salary</th>
    </tr>
</thead>

<tfoot>
    <tr>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Position</th>
        <th>Office</th>
        <th>Age</th>
        <th>Start date</th>
        <th>Salary</th>
    </tr>
</tfoot>

<tbody> 
    <tr>
        <td>Vivian Harrell</td>
        <td>Financial Controller</td>
        <td>San Francisco</td>
        <td>62</td>
        <td>2009/02/14</td>
        <td>$452,500</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Timothy Mooney</td>
        <td>Office Manager</td>
        <td>London</td>
        <td>37</td>
        <td>2008/12/11</td>
        <td>$136,200</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Jackson Bradshaw</td>
        <td>Director</td>
        <td>New York</td>
        <td>65</td>
        <td>2008/09/26</td>
        <td>$645,750</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Olivia Liang</td>
        <td>Support Engineer</td>
        <td>Singapore</td>
        <td>64</td>
        <td>2011/02/03</td>
        <td>$234,500</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Bruno Nash</td>
        <td>Software Engineer</td>
        <td>London</td>
        <td>38</td>
        <td>2011/05/03</td>
        <td>$163,500</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Sakura Yamamoto</td>
        <td>Support Engineer</td>
        <td>Tokyo</td>
        <td>37</td>
        <td>2009/08/19</td>
        <td>$139,575</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Thor Walton</td>
        <td>Developer</td>
        <td>New York</td>
        <td>61</td>
        <td>2013/08/11</td>
        <td>$98,540</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Finn Camacho</td>
        <td>Support Engineer</td>
        <td>San Francisco</td>
        <td>47</td>
        <td>2009/07/07</td>
        <td>$87,500</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Serge Baldwin</td>
        <td>Data Coordinator</td>
        <td>Singapore</td>
        <td>64</td>
        <td>2012/04/09</td>
        <td>$138,575</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Zenaida Frank</td>
        <td>Software Engineer</td>
        <td>New York</td>
        <td>63</td>
        <td>2010/01/04</td>
        <td>$125,250</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Zorita Serrano</td>
        <td>Software Engineer</td>
        <td>San Francisco</td>
        <td>56</td>
        <td>2012/06/01</td>
        <td>$115,000</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Jennifer Acosta</td>
        <td>Junior Javascript Developer</td>
        <td>Edinburgh</td>
        <td>43</td>
        <td>2013/02/01</td>
        <td>$75,650</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Cara Stevens</td>
        <td>Sales Assistant</td>
        <td>New York</td>
        <td>46</td>
        <td>2011/12/06</td>
        <td>$145,600</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Hermione Butler</td>
        <td>Regional Director</td>
        <td>London</td>
        <td>47</td>
        <td>2011/03/21</td>
        <td>$356,250</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Lael Greer</td>
        <td>Systems Administrator</td>
        <td>London</td>
        <td>21</td>
        <td>2009/02/27</td>
        <td>$103,500</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Jonas Alexander</td>
        <td>Developer</td>
        <td>San Francisco</td>
        <td>30</td>
        <td>2010/07/14</td>
        <td>$86,500</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Shad Decker</td>
        <td>Regional Director</td>
        <td>Edinburgh</td>
        <td>51</td>
        <td>2008/11/13</td>
        <td>$183,000</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Michael Bruce</td>
        <td>Javascript Developer</td>
        <td>Singapore</td>
        <td>29</td>
        <td>2011/06/27</td>
        <td>$183,000</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Donna Snider</td>
        <td>Customer Support</td>
        <td>New York</td>
        <td>27</td>
        <td>2011/01/25</td>
        <td>$112,000</td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Esto es solo un enlace y en su totalidad parece un comentario. Intenta hacer respuestas mas elaboradas. Un saludo

Comment: tampoco me ayuda mucho la pregunta, por eso he pedido que haya mas información del problema.

Comment: pero eso no se pide en una respuesta. Porque las respuestas respnonden a la pregunta, no plantean otras preguntas. para eso estan los comentarios.

Comment: por eso agregue el link , pues plantea una solución a la pregunta.

Comment: Entonces es una respuesta de baja calidad. un enlace no es una respuesta deseada. En SOes no solo se busca el solucionar el problema si no recoger preguntas y respuestas de calidad. por eso se cierran preguntas y no se dejan responder.

Comment: vale, ya hay mas info, deja respondo la pregunta mejor ok?

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/54941/discussion-between-luis-and-lois6b).

Comment: edite recien la pregunta, uso el hidden-xs, pero para eso debería poner en todos los td que deseara ocultar. Me imagino que debe existir la forma de definirlo una sola vez o mas practico.

Comment: ponselos a los tr en vez de los td.

Comment: pero si los colocos en los tr, se ocultan las filas y yo deseo que sea en las columnas

Comment: si la tabla la creas automaticamente no hay ningun  problema, ponselos a los td, si es manual , tampoco es tanto trabajo.

Comment: tenia pensado colocar algo asi:
 tabla.column(4).addClass("hidden-xs"); pero no reconoce el addClass

Answer (score 3):

Puedes probar esta función, donde si la resolucion de pantalla es menor al valor dato que oculte la columna 4,5,6

`$(document).ready(function(){
  var mq = window.matchMedia( "(max-width: 500px)" );
  // Si la medida es de 0 a 500 hace lo siguiente
  if (mq.matches) {
      $('#example>thead>tr>th:nth-of-type(4)').HiddenTables(); 
      $('#example>thead>tr>th:nth-of-type(5)').HiddenTables(); 
      $('#example>thead>tr>th:nth-of-type(6)').HiddenTables(); 
      $('#example>tfoot>tr>th:nth-of-type(4)').HiddenTables();
      $('#example>tfoot>tr>th:nth-of-type(5)').HiddenTables();

      $('#example>tfoot>tr>th:nth-of-type(6)').HiddenTables(); 
      $('#example>tbody>tr>td:nth-of-type(4)').HiddenTables(); 
      $('#example>tbody>tr>td:nth-of-type(5)').HiddenTables();
      $('#example>tbody>tr>td:nth-of-type(6)').HiddenTables(); 
  }
  jQuery.fn.HiddenTables = function()  //damos nombre ala funcion
   {
     $(this).hide();
  };`

});

Answer (score 3):

Encontre la solución, en el mismo datatable defino en el document ready, debo colocar algo asi:

```
 var tabla = $("#example").DataTable({
             "columns": [
                null,
                null,
                null,
                { "className": "hidden-xs" },
                { "className": "hidden-xs" },
                { "className": "hidden-xs" }
            ]
});
```